# problem with round shaped figures

Tags: graphics, subcaption

When I am putting two round images side by side, their shapes change to oval! here is how I do it:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.2cm, height=5.0cm]{Probabilistic_Vs_Random.png}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
 \caption{probabilistic-based player starts the game}\medskip
 \label{fig:2a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.2cm, height=5.0cm]{Random_Vs_Probabilistic.png}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}\hfill
   \caption{random player starts the game}\medskip
   \label{fig:2b}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.2cm, height=5.0cm]{Probabilistic_Vs_Probabilistic.png}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
 \caption{probabilistic vs. probabilistic}\medskip
 \label{fig:2c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Performance of random and probabilistic-based players based on 1000 plays} \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

I guess the problem is the size of my plots and this line

```
\includegraphics[width=4.2cm, height=5.0cm
```

but I  don't know how to fix. here is the snapshot

[image]

Comment: Just use _one_ (not both) of the `width=` or `height=` options to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Or use the `scale= …` option.

Comment: Or add `keepaspectratio`.

Comment: Not to sound smug, but it's always a good idea to read the manuals of all packages you include, as you might find useful, interesting and exciting options and use cases. If you'd read Graficx manual, you'd answered your own question.

Comment: @ajeh Now where is the fun in that? :P